# Reporting Error.The Report cannot be displayed(rsProcessingaborted) in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, reporting-services

I created one SSRS Report and then I deployed it on CRM.Now when I Open it i Got an Error like Reporting Error.The Report cannot be displayed(rsProcessingaborted)...I have checked that Report working well but the issue comes after when i Deployed it on CRM...Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I have run into several different problems deploying reports to CRM.  The first one I hit was trying to use a "shared connection".  CRM wants to replace your connection information when you upload the report, but it doesn't seem to be able to if the report is setup as a Shared Connection.

Take a look at [my SSRS troublshooting steps](http://edgewaters.blogspot.com/2011/01/troubleshooting-crm-ssrs-errors.html) and see if they help.  You should be able to report back a more detailed error message.